# Eccentric/collimating mechanisms in lenses - do they compensate for glass or mechanics?

Tags: lens, repair, maintenance

Some lenses include eccentric rings, or elements in adjustable via a three point fixture, or similar collimation adjustment facilities.

Do these correct for inaccuracies in the way the *glass* is manufactured (eg the lenses themselves having eccentric rims), or for inaccuracies in all the concentric metalwork? When working on such a lens (without having collimation equipment available), is it advisable to reinsert glass elements in the same rotational orientation, or should one mainly focus on disturbing eccentric metalwork as little as possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Do these correct for inaccuracies in the way the glass is manufactured
>   (eg the lenses themselves having eccentric rims), or for inaccuracies
>   in all the concentric metalwork?

Most such adjustments are for the purpose of reducing the errors caused by manufacturing tolerances with regard to the mechanisms that position and support the lens elements. Such errors are cumulative as different pieces of the lens are assembled. These adjustments are also useful as mechanical parts of the lens are affected by wear due to movement over the course of the service life of the lens. Eccentric adjustments are not generally used for correcting any manufacturing defects in the lens elements themselves.

> When working on such a lens (without having collimation equipment available), is it advisable...

When working on such a lens (without having collimation equipment available), **it is extremely advisable to not disturb such adjustments at all**. If the lens must be disassembled beyond that point, then it should probably be done by someone with the equipment (which can be fairly basic for some such tasks) and training to properly align the optical elements as the lens is reassembled.

Marking the position of such adjusting mechanisms, as well as the position of each component that affects the position of the various lens elements within the lens, is used to find a starting point close to proper alignment when the lens is reassembled. But the accuracy of such marks is generally nowhere near the degree of tolerances needed to insure the lens is optimally aligned.

Comment: I'm more about approaches to restore lenses not worth professional restoration to a serviceable state here than total perfection - if I can make a project lens worth $10 work worth $100 I am quite satisfied :) The question if there are glass-related things compensated here is important even when just taking the front lens off a wide angle, without getting near the actual eccentrics deep in the lens...

Comment: If there is no adjustment for a particular element, such as the front element of a lens, then the element should placed back in the same position it was in before being removed. Also take care to place any shims or spacers in the exact same position, including rotational position. (But that doesn't seem to me to be what your question as written is asking)